# IsPostBack and GET request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, url, get

Can a GET request cause `IsPostBAck` to be true ?

I never tried it but I read that it (somewhere) that it can be done  If I add `_ViewState`  , `_EventValidation` and `form` params.

It it true ? Can this cause a  PostBack ?

Thanks.

## edit

I found it [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=QJNoykS0Tv4C&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq=%22However,%20moving%20to%20forms%20is%20not%20enough.%20An%20attacker%20can%20easily%20build%20a%20form%20on%20his%22&source=bl&ots=JNbgq6zojQ&sig=O4sYbhSakH4K9Zo7_3CvayCV7N8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8qixUJrUNsGztAallYE4&redir_esc=y)

[image]  [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=QJNoykS0Tv4C&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq=%22However,%20moving%20to%20forms%20is%20not%20enough.%20An%20attacker%20can%20easily%20build%20a%20form%20on%20his%22&source=bl&ots=JNbgq6zojQ&sig=O4sYbhSakH4K9Zo7_3CvayCV7N8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8qixUJrUNsGztAallYE4&redir_esc=y)

## edit 2  after testing - it does WORKING

I didnt't find  **even one** topic about this in the  web.

here it is :

http://imageshack.us/f/688/croppercapture1q.gif/

Comment: @Aristos I already made see my edit2

Comment: +1, but I make some tests and tell you my results.

Comment: Im sure the @downvoter knew this.

Comment: Well, what can I say, I make it work ! you have right.... I will investigate it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a new answer after the update of the question. Actually I make a working example, **and I confirm the question**, that is can be done !

http://www.planethost.gr/SOPostBackTest.rar

What I do:

I make an aspx page, render it, then get and make an html with the render page, and just change the method from `post` to `get`

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="PostBackTest.aspx" id="form1">
```

then I open the html page, and make a `get` to the aspx page ! and the aspx page is actually see it as IsPostBack.

The results is surprise me. The Flag IsPostBack is set to TRUE, you can see and test it by your self. I do not know how to consider this - BUG, or feature that asp.net work so good that what ever you send them on the form is make it work.

And yes the `Request.HttpMethod` can show more accurate if is GET or POST command.

Comment: I just creted a button , pressed it , view source , copy the fields to the URL and  press enter.